# Prove this inequality: $\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{c+a}{\sqrt{b}}+\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{c}}\geq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}+3$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, muirhead-inequality

> Let $a$,$b$,$c$ be positive real numbers such that $abc=1$. Prove that
>   $$\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{c+a}{\sqrt{b}}+\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{c}}\geq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}+3$$

I tried various methods. But, couldn't solve it. It'd be great if anyone can help.

Comment: That looks like AM-GM. Tried with a suitable combination of te ms?

Comment: @Macavity I tried everything I could come up with. Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: That's a substantial change to do after 6 hours, even though it can be tackled easily with AM-GM.  Best to post a different question and reverse this change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By AM-GM

$$\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{c+a}{\sqrt{b}}+\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{c}}
\ge \frac{2\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{ca}}{\sqrt{b}}+\frac{2\sqrt{ab}}{\sqrt{c}}
= \frac2a+\frac2b+\frac2c$$

For the last equality $abc=1$ was used.

Then again by AM-GM; 
$$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c \ge \frac3{\sqrt[3]{abc}}=3$$

and again by a well known inequality 
$$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c \ge \frac1{\sqrt{bc}}+\frac1{\sqrt{ca}}+\frac1{\sqrt{ab}}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$$

For the last equality $abc=1$ was used. Combine the last two inequalities to get the desired result.

Comment: Nice +1.  Your well known inequality can be shown easily through AM-GM or Rearrangement... Sad thing is the OP not doing his share of basic effort.

Answer (score 4):

You already have a proof using AM-GM and Muirhead.  For a pure AM-GM proof, note that $\frac12 \left(\frac{a}b+\frac{b}a\right) \geqslant 1$ and so on, so half the LHS takes care of the $3$ on RHS.

For the rest, note you can cyclically sum the (weighted) AM-GMs:
$$\frac5{18} \left(\frac{a}b+\frac{a}c\right)+\frac2{18} \left(\frac{b}a+\frac{b}c\right)+\frac2{18} \left(\frac{c}a+\frac{c}b\right)\geqslant \frac{\sqrt[3]a}{\sqrt[6]{b c}}=\sqrt{a}$$

Comment: This is somewhat more understandable to me.

Comment: If it helps, you could do the second in two steps, $a/b+a/c \ge 2a/\sqrt{bc} = 2\sqrt{a^3}$ and then show a convex combination of $\sqrt{a^3}, \sqrt{b^3}, \sqrt{c^3}$ can you $\sqrt{a}$ etc.

Comment: I've updated the question. It was a typing mistake. I apologize. Can you work it out now?

Comment: That's too large a typo after too long.  Not going to try if you keep changing the question.

Comment: I know. But, this one is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Id est, we need to prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c-a^{\frac{4}{3}}b^{\frac{5}{6}}c^{\frac{5}{6}}-abc)\geq0$

which is AM-GM and Muirhead because $(2,1,0)\succ\left(\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{6},\frac{5}{6}\right)$

Your another problem can be solved by the same way.

Comment: Sorry. But, I cannot understand what you said. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @SayantanSantra You might read a bit about [Muirhead's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality) and [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) on Wikipedia. (And in many other places.)

Answer (score 1):

The original post was to show that
$$\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c}\ge
\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}+3.
$$
Observe that
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{a}&\ge2\sqrt{\frac{c}{b}}=2c\sqrt{a},\\
\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}&\ge2\sqrt{\frac{c}{a}}=2c\sqrt{b},\\
\frac{c}{a}+\frac{c}{b}&\ge2\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{ab}}=2c\sqrt{c}.
\end{align}
and similarly
\begin{align}
&\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}\ge2b\sqrt{a},
&\frac{b}{a}+\frac{b}{c}\ge2b\sqrt{b},
&&\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b}{c}\ge2b\sqrt{c};\\
&\frac{a}{b}+\frac{a}{c}\ge2a\sqrt{a},
&\frac{b}{c}+\frac{a}{b}\ge2a\sqrt{b},
&&\frac{c}{b}+\frac{a}{c}\ge2a\sqrt{c}.
\end{align}
So, by combining them, and use the fact that $a+b+c\ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}=3$, we have
\begin{align}
3\left(\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c}\right)
&\ge 2(a+b+c)\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)\\
&\ge 6\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right).
\end{align}
That is, 
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c}\right)\ge\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}.\tag{1}$$ Next, we also have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c}\right)
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{b}\right)
+\left(\frac{c}{b}+\frac{b}{c}\right)+\left(\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)\right]\\
&\ge \frac{1}{2}(2+2+2)\\
&=3.\tag{2}
\end{align}
Hence the result follows by combining $(1)$ and $(2)$.